# How to override a Log4j value from a shell script?

Tags: java, linux, apache-kafka, log4j, confluent-platform

I am using connect-log4j properties for logging when the Kafka JDBC Sink Connector starts.
I am trying to override a value from my shell script in connect-log4j.properties.

My Shell Script:

> echo "Starting consumer"
>
> /bin/connect-distributed -daemon /connect/connect-distributed.properties.

My log4j properties:

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file base.log.dir=/kafka/logs/

//Get the process.name from Shell script command

> process.name=**?????**
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n
> log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
> log4j.appender.file.File=${base.log.dir}/${process.name}.log

I was able to create a log by passing the process.name=test which creates test.log. But I am unable to find any information to override the 'process.name' value from my shell script. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could accomplish what you are trying to do using Log4J MDC?  http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Comment: Hey @djangofan I went through that website. It has very good content and I went through this code snippet:
   
 public void run() {
        MDC.put("transaction.id", tx.getTransactionId());
        MDC.put("transaction.owner", tx.getSender());
        log4jBusinessService.transfer(tx.getAmount());
        MDC.clear();


But in my scenario, I have to pass a value to process.name in connect-log4j.properties using shell script.